# Django POST Serializers Foreignkey Nested Data

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

Hi I am new to django serializers.facing small issue with the POST serializers.

models.py

```
class emp_shifts(models.Model):
    emp_id                  =   models.ForeignKey('emp_details')
    emp_shift_id            =   models.ForeignKey('shift_master')             
    emp_weekdays            =   models.BooleanField()
    emp_weekends            =   models.BooleanField()
    emp_isactive            =   models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        db_table            =   'emp_shifts'

views.py
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def createEmpShift(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        serializer = empAllShiftsSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors)

serializers.py
class empListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = emp_details
        #fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('emp_created_by','emp_created_time','emp_updated_by','emp_updated_time')

class allShiftsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = shift_master
        fields = ('emp_shift_id','emp_shift_name','emp_shift_from','emp_shift_to')

class empAllShiftsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emp_id = empListSerializer()
    emp_shift_id = allShiftsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = emp_shifts
        fields = '__all__'
```

i am unable to save the data.
If i send

```
{
    "emp_code":"R103AB",
    "shift_name":"Morning Shift",
    "emp_weekdays":1,
    "emp_weekends":0,
    "isactive":1
}
```

from Postman its giving the error

```
{
  "emp_id": [
    "This field is required."
  ],
  "emp_shift_id": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

i know the problem here.I need to pass the emp_id,emp_shift_id from the Foreignkey relation table.
I am able to get the emp_code primary key and shift_name primary key.But how to send that two values to the

> empAllShiftsSerializer()

here to POST the data successfully.
please correct me if i am wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to override the method create in the `empAllShiftsSerializer` serializer.

Take a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Basically, overriding this method you can define that you want to receive the pk for the foreign objects, get the objects and add in the object that you are creating.

Example:

```
    class empAllShiftsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        emp_id = empListSerializer()
        emp_shift_id = allShiftsSerializer()
        class Meta:
            model = emp_shifts
            fields = '__all__'
        def create(self, validated_data):
            emp_id = validated_data.pop('emp_id')
            emp_shift_id = validated_data.pop('emp_shift_id')
            emp_object = emp_details.objects.get(pk=emp_id)
            emp_shift_object = shift_master.objects.get(pk=emp_shift_id)

            emp_shift_object = emp_shifts.objects.create(emp=emp_object, emp_shift=emp_shift_object, **validation_data)

            return emp_shift_object
```

**Note:** I didn't test this code, it's only an example to explain better my response.

Comment: Can i save data from emp_shifts.objects.create() from views.py without using serializers ?

Comment: I think yes, you can. But, as I put in the answer, the best option is to override the create method in the Serializer class, so you continue using the serializers.